# reset margin of an specific element

Tags: html, css

I have an Image at top of my page:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="back"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#back{
    padding: 10em 0 10em;
    background: url(img/img.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;

    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This works good but I want the vertical margins to be zero I tried `margin:0;` as well as `margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;` but it didn't worked.
Using `*{margin:0}` does the job but I it effects other elements which I don't want please suggest some fix for this.

Comment: If `margin:0;` on `#back` doesn't work but `*{margin-0;}` works then some other element should be causing the issue.

Comment: I tested it on an blank page with nothing other than this yet the same issue.

Comment: It could then be the `body` tag's default browser styling. Try with `body{margin: 0;}`. If it works then that is the issue.

Comment: Your code is correct [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbL8n/1/). You might had done other mistake.

Comment: But it effects other elements too is there any way I can set this specifically for this DIV Tag.

Comment: you need style in body margin 0 and #back{
    background: url(img/img.jpg) no-repeat fixed center top transparent; min-width: width picture; min-height: height picture; display: block;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `*{margin:0;}` Works The Problem is the default margin set by browser to its parent(`<body>`)
You should reset it using:

```
body{margin:0;}
```

If this *effects other elements* as said in question you can easily manage this by adding this rule on effected elements:

```
margin: auto 1em;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the back element, but with a parent one, in this context, I guess you have to apply it to the body:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Check all parents, that's the key.

Comment: But it effects other elements too is there any way I can set this specifically for this DIV Tag.

Comment: This only affect the body, but of course, its wrap all elemnt. You have a problem understanding basic HTML structure and CSS

Comment: Applying this will make me add margin to each other elements is there any way I can Make margin of body to 0 only for this div tag ?

Comment: This will set body margin to 0, then target other element. Please, consider check basic html and css in order to understand your ploblem.

Answer (score 1):

find its parent element. I mean if it has added directly in `<body>` add this

**css:**

```
body
{
  margin : 0px;
  padding : 0px; 
}
```

It will be helpful if you give your website link. So visitors can find exact problem.

Comment: But it effects other elements too is there any way I can set this specifically for this DIV Tag.

Answer (score 1):

if its parent is <body> , so see its padding or margin. e.g. If it is 10px, use this css:
`#back
{
 margin-left : -10px;
 margin-right: -10px
}`

Answer (score -1):

Use negative value for margin in this case
for example

`#back{
    margin: -5px;
}`

set the negative value according to your need -10, -5, -8 or what ever it may fits your need

Comment: why 
is this correct
#back{
margin-left: -5px;
}
if this too is wrong give me a reason.